# finding input in selected database table column for last entry of selected identifier

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column on my table which is intended to return the last date in which I worked for a particular company.
For my query, I dont think that I can rely on timestamps as some entries are entered into the ystem in advance, for example I might work for a company today and get contracted back next week, I would update both jobs (todays and next weeks) today after work has been completed.

Table1 is of the form (arranged by date, not necessarily the date populated(timestamp))

```
 companyname  |  job  |  date    |  payment  | cost   
==================================================== 
 Company A    | JobA  | 01/09/19 |   £100    |  £50 
 Company B    | JobB  | 02/09/19 |   £100    |  £50 
 Company A    | JobC  | 03/09/19 |   £100    |  £50 
 Company B    | JobD  | 04/09/19 |   £100    |  £50 
 Company A    | JobE  | 05/09/19 |   £100    |  £50 
 Company B    | JobF  | 06/09/19 |   £100    |  £50 
 Company A    | JobG  | 07/09/19 |   £100    |  £50
```

Table 2

```
 companyname  |  income  |  profit  | avgmarkup | lastjob   
==========================================================
 Company A    |          |          |            |  
 Company B    |          |          |            |
```

Currently I am able to populate the Income and profit fields but am struffling with the `Avg Markup` and `Last job` fields

Current code to populate Table 2

```
<table id="client-table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="client-id">ID</th>
            <th>companyame</th>
            <th>income</th>
            <th>profit</th>
            <th>avgmarkup</th>
            <th>lastjob</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT `Table2`.*, SUM(`Table1`.`payment`) AS payment,
                SUM(`Table1`.`payment` - `Table1`.`cost`) AS profit,
                SUM(((`Table1`.`payment` - `Table1`.`cost`) / `Table1`.`cost`)*100) AS markup
                FROM `Table2` 
                LEFT JOIN `Table1` ON `Table1`.`customer` = `Table2`.`Table2` 
                GROUP BY `Table2`.`id`";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo "<tr>
                <td class='client-id'>".$result['id']."</td>
                <td>".$result['company']."</td>   <----- Pulled from database table
                <td>".$result['payment']."</td>
                <td>".$result['profit']."</td>
                <td>".$result['markup']."</td> <-----Markup not giving correct answer
                <td></td> <------Last job date should go here
                </tr>";
            }
        } else { 
            echo "0 results";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The formula for markup is:

```
((money_in - money_out) / money_out)*100
```

So taking this I have used - a above

```
SUM(((`Table1`.`payment` - `Table1`.`cost`) / `Table1`.`cost`)*100) AS markup
```

Which does not give a true answer....

However, my main query is based around the last job.

I have set the date type as `date` so in the database it should be recognised as such...

Is there such a way for me to link each caompany to the last date shown for them in table 1 and display that date in table 2?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxX5DdKdiMF9fqQy1yNqF7/16

Sorry if long winded and I hope someone can help :-)

Comment: Please share a dbfiddle so we can also help based on sample data.

Comment: @JitendraYadav Fiddle added :-)

Comment: Will check after office :)

Comment: @JitendraYadav that would be great, the answer from nbk below seems to be close to what Im after but I cant seem to get it to work with my table set up

Comment: Sure dude will check

Comment: what issue you are facing with nbk solution. Can you please share

Comment: Im honestly not sure... the solution works on DBfiddle but not on my live site... I have set up the `<th>title</th>` and need the solution to give me an answer that I can insert similar to `<td>".$result['profit']."</td>` currently I cannot get markup or lastjobdate to work correctly

Comment: @JitendraYadav I am thinking it might be my understanding more than anything thats letting me down

Comment: There might be some chances. Let me check it again. Will let you know in 5 minutes.

Comment: first of all for correct value of `markup` change `SUM(((Table1.payment - Table1.cost) / Table1.cost)*100)` to `SUM(Table1.payment - Table1.cost) / SUM(Table1.cost)*100` as mentioned in answer.

Comment: Below answer contains `t1.lastjob lastjob` use it to show in your html `<td>".$result['lastjob']."</td>` and you are good to go. Try and let me know.

Comment: I've changed the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxX5DdKdiMF9fqQy1yNqF7/58) Try and let me know, how it works for you.

Comment: @JitendraYadav perfect, thats exactly what I needed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our conversation. Here is the query for your data.

```
SELECT `Table2`.*, SUM(`Table1`.`payment`) AS money_in,
SUM(`Table1`.`payment` - `Table1`.`cost`) AS profit,
SUM(`Table1`.`payment` - `Table1`.`cost`) / SUM(`Table1`.`cost`)*100 AS markup,
MAX(`Table1`.`date`) AS `lastjob`
FROM `Table2` 
LEFT JOIN `Table1` ON `Table1`.`company` = `Table2`.`companyname` 
GROUP BY `Companyname`,`id`;
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxX5DdKdiMF9fqQy1yNqF7/58) for the same.

Do update your php code to show it in frontend.

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo "<tr>
                <td class='client-id'>".$result['id']."</td>
                <td>".$result['company']."</td>   <----- Pulled from database table
                <td>".$result['payment']."</td>
                <td>".$result['profit']."</td>
                <td>".$result['markup']."</td> <-----Markup not giving correct answer
                <td>".$result['lastjob']."</td> <------Last job date should go here
                </tr>";
            }
```

Comment: Can I trouble you with one more question... to use SUM() based on conditions and take from a different table...  for example table 3 has different info and am trying to add `SUM(CASE WHEN table3.variable= 'Y' then (Sum(1.2 * table1.payment)) - SUM(table1.payment)) as total`

Comment: sure send me the link for that too.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwbfydDFK3dKrKP1z7NznH/2 I have  tried to explain as good as I can

Comment: please print the expected output in comments too.

Comment: Expected output would be 80... 4 values with 'Y' each calculated at (cost*1.2)-cost

Comment: Did my output make sense? I wasn't sure how to explain

Comment: It will be a similar calculation to vat_in, only I want the payment info to come from table1.cost but only got drives who have table2.variable=Y

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where your add your pound sign.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`id` INT(1),
 `company` varchar(9), 
 `job` varchar(4), 
 `date` date, 
 `payment` varchar(4), 
 `cost` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `company`, `job`, `date`, `payment`, `cost`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Company A', 'JobA', '2019-01-09', '120', '100'),
    (2, 'Company B', 'JobB', '2019-02-09', '120', '100'),
    (3, 'Company A', 'JobC', '2019-03-09', '120', '100'),
    (4, 'Company B', 'JobD', '2019-04-09', '120', '100'),
    (5, 'Company A', 'JobE', '2019-05-09', '120', '100'),
    (6, 'Company B', 'JobF', '2019-06-09', '120', '100'),
    (7, 'Company A', 'JobG', '2019-07-09', '120', '100')
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
    ( `id` int,
     `companyname` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`id`,`companyname`)
VALUES
    (1,'Company A'),
    (2,'Company B');
```

this Select statement

```
SELECT 
 `Table2`.*
 , SUM(`Table1`.`payment`) AS money_in
 ,SUM(`Table1`.`payment` - `Table1`.`cost`) AS profit
 ,SUM(`Table1`.`payment` - `Table1`.`cost`) / SUM(`Table1`.`cost`)*100 AS markup
 ,t1.`lastjob` `lastjob`
 FROM `Table2` 
LEFT JOIN `Table1` ON `Table1`.`company` = `Table2`.`companyname`
inner JOIN (SELECT MAX(`date`) `lastjob`, `company` 
             FROM `Table1`
              GROUP BY `company`) t1 ON `Table1`.`company` = t1.`company`
GROUP BY Table2.`Companyname`,Table2.`id`;
```

Gets you following result.

```
id  companyname     money_in    profit  markup  lastjob
1   Company A       480         80      20      2019-07-09
2   Company B       360         60      20      2019-06-09
```

This math works.

The last job day you have to self join table1 here as t1, to get the correct date for last job

Comment: Thank you for your answer.As easy as it probably should be, I cannot manage to take your info above and translate it into what I need. I have made a fiddle - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxX5DdKdiMF9fqQy1yNqF7/16 to show what I have got currenlty, any help ammending that would be great, if possible...

Comment: Also, I shouldnt have put the `£` in the table above, that was an error. I add the currency symbol with CSS - `.currency::before{content:"£";}`. Although I was wondering, the way that you added it here, would that be a better way to do it? the problem with the integers is that they dont have a separator, they read `£1000` rather than `£1,000`

Comment: Sure i changed  my answer that it will giv the right answer.

Comment: Thank, ive been messing around with this for the last hour and cant get it to work in my own table... Say you set a last job heading - `<th>last Job date</th>` and wanted to populate the rows with `<td>".$result['lastjobdate']."</td>` how would I alter the code to achieve this? as that is what I have done with the rest I have set as, for example `SUM('Table1'.'payment') AS payment,` which populates `<td>".$result['profit']."</td>`

Comment: Im not sure if the ``t1.`lastjob` `lastjob` is affecting things?

Comment: it affects nothing it add two fields one is the company name (i would haved used the the id from table2 alsi in table1) the other is the newest date that is in the row of the company) that is added to every row in table1. As you can see in the example it works. so treid in in your original table. simpy add the code replace table1 with your table name and see what happens. If you really want to see, don' group your Select there will see all columsn and rows that are created by your joins.